# How to manually turn off a condition thru frontend javascript

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a function on my django app that automatically executes when certain conditions are met.

Now I want to happen is, the user have the ability to turn on/off that automatic feature on a toggle button.

@views.py

```
def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        created_gt=now() - timedelta(days=3),
        sms_sent=False,
    )
    if responses.count() >= 50:
        send_sms()
        responses.update(sms_sent=True)
```

@urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('send_sms/', send_sms, name='send_sms'), ## To execute this, call the API endpoint from vue
    path('auto_sms/', auto_sms, name='auto_sms'), ## There must be a toggle button for on & off.
]
```

How to do it? I mean what logic or condition. I'm using DRF-VueJS Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is,add a field to the model which says if the feature is on or off,and in your condition it will go like this:

```
if responses.count() >= 50 and feature==True:
```

As for turning the condition on or off,you can add a view for that maybe.